# Checking 2 columns for equality, if equal make a new col

Tags: r

If

```
data$col1==data$col2
```

Then

```
data$newcol==data$col1
```

Elseif

```
data$col3==data$col2
```

Then

```
data$newcol==data$col2
```

I want rows not to loose their identity

Answer (score 1):

A column has to have some value for every row, even if you don't want to define it.  I think you can try using `ifelse` here:

```
data$newcol = ifelse(data$col1 == data$col2, data$col1, NA)
```

In the event that a given row has `col1` not equal to `col2`, `NA` would be assigned to the new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach using `dplyr::mutate()`

```
library(dplyr) # 0.7.4

set.seed(10)

dtf <- data_frame(
    col1 = sample(1:20, 10),
    col2 = sample(1:20, 10),
    col3 = sample(1:20, 10)
)


dtf %>%
    mutate(new_col = case_when(
               col1 == col2 ~ col1,
               col3 == col2 ~ col2,
               TRUE ~ NA_integer_
           ))
```